# play framework 2 promise status

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

In play 2.1 I can execute a block of code asynchronously with Akka like this:

```
Promise<Integer> promiseOfInt = Akka.future(
  new Callable<Integer>() {
    public Integer call() {
      return intensiveComputation();
    }
  }
);
```

How I can get status of this operation?
For example: started, performed, completed, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three callbacks you could use `onSuccess`, `onFailure` and `onComplete`.

See the "Callbacks" section here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/scala/futures.html